# Dart Mockito - stub a field

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

Using mockito

```
  group("VgnItmFormEvents", () {
    setUp(() {
      mockStore = MockManageVgnItmStore();
      when(mockStore.formType).thenReturn(const Edit());// if I leave this line out I get missing stub error
})
```

This test fails:

```
test('OnNameChanged', () async {
  mockStore.formType = Add(name: 'add');
  expect(mockStore.formType, Add(name: 'add'));
});
```

The line with the code comment is the culprit, but without it, I get a missing stub error. How do I make the mock have `mockStore.formType` as a settable field that I can check what it was set to?

This is the actual field on the real object:

```
  FormType get formType => stateNotifiersVm.formType;
  set formType(FormType formType) =>
      stateNotifiersVm.formTypeStateNotifier.setState(formType);
```

This is the stateNotifiersVm:

```
  FormType get formType => _formType;
  set formType(FormType formType) => formTypeStateNotifier.setState(formType);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `verify` if a setter was called with a specific value without having to call the getter (and thus hitting the missing stub error):

```
@GenerateMocks([Cat])
import 'cat.mocks.dart';

class Cat {
  int _formType = 0;

  int get formType => _formType;
  set formType(int ft) => _formType = ft;
}

void main() {
  final cat = MockCat();

  test('can set formType', () {
    cat.formType = 8;
    verify(cat.formType = 8);
  });
}
```

Is this what you were looking for? Sadly mockito does not have a way to call the "real" method underneath as far as i know.

Comment: Thank you. This works and completely answers the question. I made the question a little bit too simplified because I didn't know it could work as you showed. If instead of doing `cat.formType = 8`, I was to do `underTest.doFunctionThatSetsCatFormTypeToEight(cat)`, and then `verify(cat.formType = 8);`, that is what I actually need, and I get the missing stub error.